# Unable to create Dashboard report folder on jenkins

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am able to create a dashboard folder on Local jenkins but same when I am trying to deploy on live jenkins following error I am getting.

Error generating the report: org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Cannot create working directory "temp/latencyVsRequest"

Even My JTL file is properly created but folder is not getting created

Following is the command which I have put in Jenkins Execution shell

cd /mnt/apache-jmeter-5.4/bin

sh jmeter -n -t /mnt/qa/erosnow-auto-test/JMeterAutomation/TestingScript.jmx -l /mnt/qa/erosnow-auto-test/JMeterAutomation/test123.jtl -e -o /mnt/qa/erosnow-auto-test/JMeterAutomation/test123

Answer (score 0):

The message means that the user you're running Jenkins from doesn't have sufficient permissions to create `temp/latencyVsRequest` folder in your Jenkins workspace, you need to either grant the user the appropriate rights via [chown](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) command or change `jmeter.reportgenerator.temp_dir` property to point to some path where your user has write access.

More information:

- [Create file in folder: permission denied](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119358/create-file-in-folder-permission-denied)
- [JMeter Properties Reference - Reporting Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your reply, Can you please tell me where can I change the jmeter.reportgenerator.temp_dir and in which file

Comment: "In which file": *user.properties*, "where can I change" - I don't know, it's your Jenkins, not mine, theoretically the folder where JMeter stores .jtl file should be a good choice, given you have write permissions to parent you should be able to create new folders there as well